# jekyll-sitemap and robots.txt get wrapped in html unexpectedly when generating jekyll site

Tags: html, xml, jekyll, sitemap, jekyll-extensions

My sitemap.xml and robots.txt, generated by jekyll-sitemap, get wrapped in html for some reason, which makes them non-compliant.

I'm using the jekyll-sitemap plugin, verified, that it is the latest version (https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap) and tried a number of other things, mostly various ways of setting `layout: none` via front matter and conf.

If I create a random text or xml file, they do not end up being wrapped in html.

I also tried to disable all the plugins and default layout settings as well as the `compress` layout, but cannot find the cause for this.

Did someone come across such an issue? Any ideas how to debug this?

sitemap.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html><body>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
...
actual sitemap goes here
...
</body></html>
```

[EDIT] When I do create a random file *with* frontmatter it does get wrapped, even when I add `layout: none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this happens in conjunction with the jekyll-external-links plugin (https://github.com/riboseinc/jekyll-external-links). When deactivating jekyll-external-links in the Gemfile, jekyll-sitemap produces the robot.txt and sitemap.xml files without error.

There is a fork of jekyll-external-links, that addresses this issue: https://github.com/Rp70/jekyll-external-links

To use this for instead of the original you can replace the Gemfile entry of the original plugin with this line:

> gem 'jekyll-external-links', :git => 'https://github.com/Rp70/jekyll-external-links'

This will pull in the forked repo and install the gem from there. The fork works as advertised and doesn't touch any non-html files, which is the source of the error.